# How to Filldown Vlookup on a Filtered Range | Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

Thanks for your help! Need assistance in the vba for writing a macro that filters my data, and then applies a vlookup to only the filtered range.

ex)

**OrderTable** - List of Orders and their corresponding Statuses, (Some simple, some vague)

**StatusTable** - Contains a list of all the vague Orders, but with more more detailed information

Each table is contained on a separate tab within the same worksheet. I need assistance in **writing the VBA** for filtering the OrderTable to *only* the vague status orders, followed by a vlookup filldown, so that we might reference the StatusDetails table to retrieve the more accurate statuses. We need to be abel to retain the original status if not "vague", so an =iferror wont' help out here

*(Essentially, we're making an excel left join on "vague" orders)*

This all occurs on a worksheet with thousands of orders, (with much more complex descriptions being pulled in), multiple times a day.

Order table

[image: OrderTable]

status table

[image: StatusTable]

The problem I'm encountering is that this is a dynamic range, after filtering... the order in cell B3 is not always "vague", the first "vague" cell in the range may sometimes be B2 or B5, depending on which orders are yet to be fulfilled

```
Sub Test_macro()

    Range("$A$1:$B$6").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="Vague"
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(B3),StatusTable!A:B,2,0)"
    Sheet1.Range("B3", "B" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).FillDown

End Sub
```

Thanks for your patience here

Comment: Why filter? Just apply a Vlookup with an error catch, so only the found ones get filled in.

Comment: So you want to so this in place?  Then filter on `Vague` you do that with the filter on the data tab.  once filtered put in the VLOOKUP and fill down.  Then remove the filter.  The formula will only be put in the visible cells.  Not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Manual filtering and pasting a formula isn't an option, as noted in my question -- this needs to be done using VBA, (it is applicable to multiple identical worksheets with thousands of orders)

Comment: Well then you will need to write that vba, and come here for specific help with code that is not working.  Stack Overflow is not a code for me site.

Comment: Copy that, just need to be pointed in the right direction here for what to begin researching. (Was hoping the solution was simple)

Comment: please put the code in the original post and not the comments.  comments can not be formatted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SpecialCells

```
Sub Test_macro()

Sheet1.Range("A1:B6").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="Vague"
Sheet1.Range("B2:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],StatusTable!C1:C2,2,FALSE)"
Sheet1.ShowAllData

End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect! You are amazing

Answer (score 0):

Why filter? Just apply a Vlookup with an error catch.

```
=iferror(Vlookup(bla),"")
```

Comment: Unfortunately, need to be able to maintain the original order status is it's not "vague."   ie., besides "good" there could be "great", "awesome", etc.  sorry for not mentioning that in the original post!

Comment: That does not matter. My point is that you can use a Vlookup on the whole list, not just a filtered list. Use conditions in a wrapped error catch to apply the vlookup only on rows you want.